# TYPO3 10 upload multiple images from frontend by extending model

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I am trying to extend the model of `Ext:cart`. While someone orders a product from the cart page. I would like to accept images from users.

I have added the below configuration for the same.

**Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_cart_domain_model_order_item.php**

```
<?php

$temporaryColumns = [
    'images' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 'Upload Image',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('images', [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ],
                'maxitems' => 1,
                // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
                // to use the imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
                'foreign_match_fields' => [
                    'fieldname' => 'images',
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_cart_domain_model_order_item',
                    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                ],
                'foreign_types' => [
                    '0' => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ]
                ]
            ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'])
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tx_cart_domain_model_order_item',
    $temporaryColumns
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tx_cart_domain_model_order_item',
    'images',
    '',
    'after:comment'
);
```

**ext_localconf.php**

```
$dispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher::class);
$dispatcher->connect(
    \Extcode\Cart\Utility\OrderUtility::class,
    'changeOrderItemBeforeSaving',
    \vendor\myext\Utility\OrderUtility::class,
    'changeOrderItemBeforeSaving'
);

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\Extcode\Cart\Domain\Model\Order\Item::class] = [
    'className' => \vendor\myext\Domain\Model\Order\Item::class
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class)
    ->registerImplementation(
        \Extcode\Cart\Domain\Model\Order\Item::class,
        \vendor\myext\Domain\Model\Order\Item::class
    );
```

**Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

return [
    \Extcode\Cart\Domain\Model\Order\Item::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_cart_domain_model_order_item'
    ],
];
```

**Model: Classes/Domain/Model/Order/Item.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\myext\Domain\Model\Order;

/*
 * This file is part of the package extcode/cart.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

class Item extends \Extcode\Cart\Domain\Model\Order\Item
{

    /**
     * images
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
     */
    protected $images = NULL;

    /**
     * __construct
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initStorageObjects();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
     * Do not modify this method!
     * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
     * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initStorageObjects() {
        $this->images = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }

    /**
     * Removes a FileReference
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $imageToRemove The FileReference to be removed
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeImage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $imageToRemove) {
        $this->images->detach($imageToRemove);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the images
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $images
     */
    public function getImages() {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the images
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $images
     * @return void
     */
    public function setImages(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $images) {
        $this->images = $images;
    }

}
```

Now, I have created a utility class to modify orderItem while placing an order. But, I am not getting an extended images field.

```
<?php

namespace vendor\myext\Utility;

/*
 * This file is part of the package extcode/cart.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class OrderUtility
{
    /**
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function changeOrderItemBeforeSaving(array $params) {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($params);die;
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide how to extend any extension with FAL image and extend with standalone extension.

Comment: Long ago, Helmut wrote a blog article about creating FAL relations via frontend. His sample code got an extension: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example

Comment: Yes, but it's a standalone extension that has its own controller and action. While we override model to the custom extension we don't have that. And the extension you refere is too old TYPO3 6! I made it compatible with TYPO3 8 and TYPO3 9 but its not working correctly. See here: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/pull/35

Comment: Aehm, it's compatible with TYPO3 v10 (https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/commit/9844273df6c0efc7fad4f02ce473ec4eefdb6114) - and it's working fine in one of our v10 projects...

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but couple years back for a 9.5 project I made an helper class to attach media to objects. This one is limited to images, Youtube and Vimeo, but not very hard to extend to other media types if needed. It's not ideal but it's working, I hope it helps someone.

```
/**
 * Attach an image file or Youtube / Vimeo movie to an object with add method
 * 
 * Jacco van der Post - 2019
 * jacco@id-webdesign.nl
 *
 * @param string|array $uploadFile
 * @param object $obj
 * @param int $storageUid
 * @param string $storageFolder
 * @param string $propertyName
 * @param bool $deleteFile
 * @param bool $add Adding instead of setting
 * @param bool $video Is the file a video
 *
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\ExistingTargetFileNameException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\ExistingTargetFolderException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\InsufficientFolderAccessPermissionsException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\InsufficientFolderWritePermissionsException
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\ResourceDoesNotExistException
 *
 */
public static function attachFile($uploadFile, $obj, int $storageUid = 1, string $storageFolder = '', string $propertyName = 'logo', bool $deleteFile = false, bool $add = false, bool $video = false)
{
    $propertyName = htmlspecialchars($propertyName);
    $validMedia = false;
    $videoFile = null;

    $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    $resourceFactory = ResourceFactory::getInstance();
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\StorageRepository $storageRepository */
    $storageRepository = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository');
    $storage = $storageRepository->findByUid(intval($storageUid));    // 1 ==> default to fileadmin

    $folder = htmlspecialchars($storageFolder);
    $targetFolder = null;
    if ($storage->hasFolder($folder)) {
        $targetFolder = $storage->getFolder($folder);
    } else {
        $targetFolder = $storage->createFolder($folder);
    }

    if ($video && $uploadFile) {
        $youTubeHelper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\OnlineMedia\Helpers\YouTubeHelper::class, 'youtube');

        // Is it a Youtube link?
        $videoFile = $youTubeHelper->transformUrlToFile(htmlspecialchars($uploadFile), $targetFolder);

        // Is it a Vimeo link?
        if (is_null($videoFile)) {
            $vimeoHelper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\OnlineMedia\Helpers\VimeoHelper::class, 'vimeo');
            $videoFile = $vimeoHelper->transformUrlToFile(htmlspecialchars($uploadFile), $targetFolder);
            if (is_null($videoFile)) {
                //throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Invalid Youtube or Vimeo link..');
                if (is_object($obj)) {
                    return $obj;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        $validMedia = true;
    } else {
        // It's supposed to be an image
        // Prevent script upload instead of image files
        if (exif_imagetype(htmlspecialchars($uploadFile['tmp_name'])) && getimagesize(htmlspecialchars($uploadFile['tmp_name']))) {
            $validMedia = true;
        }
    }

    if ($validMedia && is_object($obj)) {
        if ($deleteFile) {
            // Delete older file if needed, works only for model with maxitems 1 file
            $method = 'get' . ucfirst($propertyName);

            if ($obj->{$method}()) {
                $falUid = $obj->{$method}()->getUid();
                $fileReferenceObject = $resourceFactory->getFileReferenceObject($falUid);
                $fileReferenceObject->getOriginalFile()->delete();
            }
        }

        /** @var \Xxxx\Xxxx\Domain\Model\FileReference $newFileReference */
        $newFileReference = $objectManager->get('Xxx\Xxxx\Domain\Model\FileReference');

        if ($video) {
            $newFileReference->setOriginalResource($videoFile);

            if (method_exists($obj, 'getName')) {
                $newFileReference->setTitle($obj->getTitle());
            } elseif (method_exists($obj, 'getTitle')) {
                $newFileReference->setTitle($obj->getTitle());
            }
        } else {
            $originalFilePath = htmlspecialchars($uploadFile['tmp_name']);
            $newFileName = htmlspecialchars($uploadFile['name']);

            if (file_exists($originalFilePath)) {
                $movedNewFile = $storage->addFile($originalFilePath, $targetFolder, $newFileName);
                $newFileReference->setOriginalResource($movedNewFile);
                $newFileReference->setTitle($newFileName);

                if (method_exists($obj, 'getName')) {
                    $newFileReference->setAlternative($obj->getName());
                } elseif (method_exists($obj, 'getTitle')) {
                    $newFileReference->setAlternative($obj->getTitle());
                }
            }
        }

        // 'add' method to filereference when model allows for multiple images attached to object, else 'set'
        if ($add) {
            $method = 'add' . ucfirst($propertyName);
        } else {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($propertyName);
        }

        $obj->{$method}($newFileReference);
    }

    return $obj;
}
```

Note that file upload is by definition unsafe! I talked once with Helmut about this, it's very hard to prevent bad stuf. There is some validation in this script but not enough. In my case the frontend users were 'kinda trusted' with frontend logins given by admins.